# slideToggle not working on dynamically generated divs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to add a lot of

with hidden divs that slideToggle. I don't want to write such  a long code that's why I'm trying this:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >


</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this function does not work when I append the p and div
    $(".flip").click(function() {
        $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");

    });
    var p = $('<p></p>').addClass('flip').text('click here');
    var div = $('<div></div>').addClass('panel').text('hellow world');
    p.append(div);
    $(p).bind('click', function() {

     // alert($(this).text()); //this alert works when i put it as a p.bind
       $(this).next().slideToggle("slow"); //this does not work!! but the previous alert does work....
     });
    $("div#elements").append(p);


});
</script>


<style type="text/css"> 
div.panel,p.flip
{
    margin:0px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
}
div.panel
{
    height:120px;
    display:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body >

<div id="elements" >


 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Interesting thing is that the$(flip) function DOES not work with the generated p and div...I then added the function as a (p).bind, and tried it with an alert and it DOES work, but when I want to slideToggle, it doesn't work, does anybody know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Interesting thing is that the$(flip) function DOES not work with
> ```
>
> the generated p and div...

That's because your p and div elements are dynamically added and are not part of the DOM yet when the page is loaded. Have you tried using the [jQuery live API](http://api.jquery.com/live/) instead?

```
$(".flip").live("click", function() {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");

});
```

Comment: Thanks! it works with other functions like

 $(".flip").live("click", function() {
        // $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
        //  alert("hello");
  $(this).css("background-color","red");
     });
but with the toggle it still doesn't work...

Comment: It's not clear which element you are targeting with slideToggle(). If you are targeting the div element inside your p element, then you should use $(this).find("div.panel").slideToggle("slow") instead of $(this).next().slideToggle("slow"). The .next() API gets the immediately following sibling, not the immediate child.

Comment: Whoa! a million thanks! the .find works, thanks for the explanation about the .next() I thought I was getting the div with next!